# Animating Margin by ValueAnimator vs ViewPropertyAnimator translationX

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation, android-view

I am a beginner in android animation. I have few views inside a RelativeLayout and i wish to change view position. What are the options i have and how they differ?

I have tried following:

```
view.animate()
.translationX(toX)
.setDuration(duration);
```

and

```
RelativeLayout.MarginLayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.MarginLayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
ValueAnimator animator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(params.rightMargin, 100);
animator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
        params5.rightMargin = (Integer) valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue();
    }
});
```

Both changes the position of the view. Can anyone explain me the difference in these two method. What other options i have and which is the preferred option.

Answer (score 2):

```
view.animate()
.translationX(toX)
.setDuration(duration);
```

I think it's preferred one, because it doesn't call measure() and layout() on each update as the second one would.

And in general:
- translationX is meant to regulate the position of a child within its parent
- perform animation through changing margin parameter isn't a good idea (it's meant to be set once and to be changed rarely if ever)

Comment: I have updated the question. Please have a look at it and give me your valuable suggestion.

Comment: @Shubendra I also think it can be done using RelativeLayout and animating translationX.

Answer (score 1):

The first one is the best solution. It's specifically created for animations, so it's the most optimized version.
You have to keep in mind that if you animate a view then the whole layout will be recalculated with each movement (obviously for the translation, but not for an alpha for example), so you have to keep the layout tree as flat as possible. If it's possible try to avoid the `RelativeLayout`s, since they are measured twice at each frame (https://youtu.be/HXQhu6qfTVU).
You can check out a lot of cool videos here about the performance issues: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ORgucLTtTDI&list=PLWz5rJ2EKKc9CBxr3BVjPTPoDPLdPIFCE