# Android - scrolling large number of items without Scrollview/Listview/Gridview

Tags: android, android-view

I am trying to implement a special custom view that has lots of child views, and I need to implement vertical scrolling.

The ScrollView based approach is too slow since there are too many children to draw. I cannot enable hardware layer as the length of the scrolling content is too long to fit in texture size for HWUI. Software layer also fails with insufficient memory to create such a large layer.

I cannot use Listview & Gridview either for project related matters.
So, I think I am going to create `listview` like functionality by myself.

I know that for this, I have to re-use views.
Here is where I have the confusion as to how to proceed.
As the content scrolls, I can take a view from top side and move it to bottom.
I think there are 3 ways to do this.
1] `setTranslateY`
2] `offsetTopAndBottom`
3] change `layoutparams` top and bottom margins and call `requestLayout`

But, I am not sure how there are different especially [1] and [2].
Can anybody tell me how [1] and [2] are different and also, guide me on which is the right approach here to implement `listview` like scrolling, for large number of items.

Thanks,
Androbean.

Comment: `"I know that for this, I have to re-use views"` so use `RecyclerView`. docs: "Class Overview
A flexible view for providing a limited window into a large data set."

Comment: I think Recyclerview also cannot be used as the child items are not exactly a vertical list. I have child views arranged as a staggered grid. :(

Comment: see [RecyclerView.LayoutManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.LayoutManager.html)

Comment: for comparing [1] and [3] approaches please see this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/33085311/5247331

Comment: @pskink That might be promising, I will check an update here.

Comment: @VitalyZinchenko Thanks for the link. But can you tell me difference between [1] & [2] also?

Comment: @AndrobeanStudio I'm not really sure about their difference

Comment: There's also a StaggeredGridLayoutManager already included in the RecyclerView library.

Comment: @pskink I checked the documentation for [RecyclerView.LayoutManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.LayoutManager.html). But it seems like I have to rewrite everything to align with that design. I have worked out a trick to solve my issue for the time. I will post it as an answer.

Comment: @ataulm StaggeredGridLayoutManager seems very close to what I wanted. But I am making a homescreen app and it needs to do a lot of custom animations and effects while dragging etc. With my previous experience with readymade views, I think StaggeredGridLayoutManager might impose some limitations on me at some point. But its very close. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 0):

[RecyclerView.LayoutManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.LayoutManager.html) seems like a possible solution. But it is very difficult to change my design at this time to align with `RecyclerView.LayoutManager` approach.

So, I have worked out a hack which is doing the job just right for me. Scrolling is perfectly smooth and I didn't have to change a lot of code.
Posting it here for my own and others reference.

Basically I create all the child views and do add them to my custom Viewgroup. But then I override the `dispatchDraw` method to limit drawing to only those that are visible.

No recycling methods are used in this. It is just a huge `Viewgroup` wrapped inside a Scrollview.

```
@Override
protected void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    int clipSaveCount = canvas.save();
    canvas.clipRect(getScrollX() + getPaddingLeft(), getScrollY() + getPaddingTop(),
            getScrollX() + getRight() - getLeft() - getPaddingRight(),
            getScrollY() + getBottom() - getTop() - getPaddingBottom());

    int rowHeightNoGap = (getHeight() - getPaddingTop() - getPaddingBottom())/mDataScreen.getRowCount();
    int startIndex = Math.max(0, (mScrollPosY - getPaddingTop())/rowHeightNoGap * mDataScreen.getColumnCount()-1);
    int endIndex = Math.min(getChildCount()-1, startIndex + (mDataScreen.getVisibleRowCount()+1) * mDataScreen.getColumnCount());

    final long drawingTime = getDrawingTime();
    for (int i = startIndex; i <= endIndex; i++) {
        drawChild(canvas, getChildAt(i), drawingTime);
    }

    canvas.restoreToCount(clipSaveCount);
}

int mScrollPosY;
public void setScrollPosition(int scrollPosY){
    mScrollPosY = scrollPosY;
    invalidate();
}
```

Comment: which class are you modifying here?

Comment: @ataulm This is a subclass of ViewGroup which wrapped inside the Scrollview.

Comment: so this doesn't do any view recycling? It would be good if you could update your answer to make this explicit, as you mentioned you wanted view recycling in your question.

Comment: @ataulm Ok, I will add additional info in the answer. I think the title of the question is still valid.